# Any alternative of Turbo Assembler on 64 bit OS?

Tags: assembly, tasm

I am a bit new to 80x86 assembly language and we are taught to use TASM since it is the assembler installed on our laboratory PCs. Then, I wanted to practice assembly language programming at home, so I searched and downloaded TASM5 and TASMeditor since they're the ones available on the internet. However, I found out that it doesn't work on my 64 bit Windows 8 OS. Searching for "TASM 64 bit" showed how to emulate using DOSBOX, but that is too tedious and may create problems. Searching for terms "TASM alternative" yielded NASM, and YASM. YASM is a bit complicated to use, so I did not bother with it, and NASM has different syntax with TASM. So, my question is, what can I use as an alternative to TASM? With no syntax changes? Any other suggestions?

Advanced thanks!

Comment: Both NASM and MASM are not _much_ different from TASM, you should try either. They're probably the best you can afford without running TASM itself inside an emulator. Unfortunately, x86 assembly languages have neither a _de facto_ standard nor a formal standard, so listing portability between different assemblers is still a big issue nowadays.

Comment: Considering that you want to write code for 16-bit DOS, using a DosBox is likely the best alternative. 16-bit code won't run on 64-bit Windows otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the MASM32 package (AFAIU, an unofficial release of MASM, extracted from the various Windows SDKs and DDKs freely available), which is similar in syntax to TASM.

Also similar is Open Watcom's WASM and its fork JWasm.

I personally prefer NASM, which is available on more platforms than TASM and MASM, which supports a number of formats and which I feel more in control with. Also, it's not as wordy as TASM/MASM/WASM.